# How to have multiple kubernetes config and change quicky between them

Tags: azure, kubernetes, windows-10, kubectl

I am working with multiple Kubernetes clusters at Azure, so I need to change quickly from one cluster to another without having various files at my path `C:\Users\username\.kube`, because I have to rename or replace the file when I wish to change to other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest that you use the following tools and tricks:

- Use [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to manage multiple `kubectl` versions
- **[Set the `KUBECONFIG`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) env var to change between multiple `kubeconfig` files**
- Use [`kube-ps1`](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) to keep track of your current context/namespace
- Use [`kubectx` and `kubens`](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) to change fast between clusters/namespaces
- Use aliases to combine them all together

Take a look at this article, it explains how to accomplish this: [Using different kubectl versions with multiple Kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/@eduardobaitello/using-different-kubectl-versions-with-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-a3ad8707b87b)

I also recommend this read: [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you check out this tool: [kubectxwin](https://github.com/thomasliddledba/kubectxwin)

This is the Windows version of the `kubectx` tool which is the go-to for many to quickly change between clusters and namespaces within clusters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have all your kubernetes config files.

1.- Create a `config` file in the path `C:\Users\username\.kube`

2.- Get the data from every `config` file. For instance,  3 files one per environment (dev, qa, prod) so let's merge into one

Your file must looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: some_authority_01
    server: some_server_url_01
  name: some_cluster_name_01

- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: some_authority_02
    server: some_server_url_02
  name: some_cluster_name_02

- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: some_authority_03
    server: some_server_url_03
  name: some_cluster_name_03

contexts:
- context:
    cluster: some_cluster_name_01
    user: some_user_01
  name: some_cluster_name_01

- context:
    cluster: some_cluster_name_02
    user: some_user_02
  name: some_cluster_name_02

- context:
    cluster: some_cluster_name_03
    user: some_user_03
  name: some_cluster_name_03

current-context: some_cluster_name_01
kind: Config

preferences: {}
users:
- name: some_user_01
  user:
    client-certificate-data: some_certificate_01
    client-key-data: some_key_01
- name: some_user_02
  user:
    client-certificate-data: some_certificate_02
    client-key-data: some_key_02
- name: some_user_02
  user:
    client-certificate-data: some_certificate_03
    client-key-data: some_key_03
```

**Note**: the value of the current-context may vary, it isn't necessary that be the first cluster.

## Adding the Shortcuts

3.- Add shortcuts for Windows 10 for changing kubernetes context quicky
3.1.- Create a file called `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` in the path `C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`

3.2 Copy this data into the file that was recently created

```
function See-Contexts{kubectl config get-contexts}
Set-Alias -Name seec -Value See-Contexts


function change-context-01 { kubectl config use-context some_cluster_name_01}
Set-Alias -Name ctx01 -Value change-context-01

function change-context-02 { kubectl config use-context some_cluster_name_02}
Set-Alias -Name ctx01 -Value change-context-02

function change-context-03 { kubectl config use-context some_cluster_name_03}
Set-Alias -Name ctx01 -Value change-context-03
```

3.3.- Search **PowerShell** at search bar in in Windows and open the option `RUN ISE as Administrator` and open the file **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1** and run the file.

With this solution you can easily change from kubernetes cluster using a shortcut. For example if you wanna change to 
the cluster **some_cluster_name_01** you only need to type `ctx01`. This is useful when we have multiple kubernetes clusters.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants a solution for Linux: Referring to the linked [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75), we can set multiple config files in the environment variable `KUBECONFIG`:

`export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/test:~/.kube/prod`

Just put this into your `~/.bashrc` file to make it persistent.